# migrate ksh script from unix to linux

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

I need to port several hundreds of ksh scripts from SunOS 5.10 to Linux 2.6.18-231.el5.

On SunOS, ksh version is Version M-11/16/88i.
on linux, ksh Version is AJM 93t+ 2010-02-02

It seems there are lots of differnces between ksh on UNIX and Linux...

Is there any doc for the full list of the incompatibility between the ksh on UNIX vs Linux?
Could someone have any advices on this? 
Thanks,

Comment: Interesting - you must be pushing the edges of ksh; I've got lots of ksh scripts that were written on Solaris that simply work on Linux.  I've only got one (ghastly but important) script that does not work well on Linux.  One day, I'll work out what the heck is up with it.

Answer (score 1):

We have several **thousand** ksh files that we use to test our components on AIX, HP/UX, Solaris and now RHEL 5 and we found that zsh was the closest in behaviour, on Linux, to the Korn shells on the other platforms.  We installed zsh and symlinked it to /bin/ksh and were pretty happy with the results.

Comment: I am afraid I can not install zsh and link it to /bin/ksh since there will be other applications are using ksh..

Comment: by using zsh there will be no change needed for the scripts? 
Thanks for your reply:)

Comment: Correct, providing you create a link from /bin/ksh.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the biggest difference will be the arguments and options for external utilities. The Korn shell code itself should be portable.

As an example, `find` has a few options in the Solaris version that are not in the GNU version.